# How to open IE from a java program

Tags: java, cmd, java-15

Hey I tried to open IE from a java program.
the command `start iexplorer` works on command prompt and terminal but when used in a java program throws a IOException. When I execute the command `cmd start iexplorer` the program is just running without stopping for almost 15 minutes

```
 String command = "cmd start iexplore";
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            p.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This is the call stack of from VScode:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYGm8.png)

can someone help me with this please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you are doing is running "cmd" in background. If iexplore is on your system Path then this may work:

```
String[] cmd = new String[] {"cmd", "/c", "start iexplore"};
```

The "/c" option tells CMD.EXE to start the process, and then CMD exits immediately [in your case it is hanging around for more input]. Also you need to read the STDERR stream of the process to see any error messages from CMD.